# Are there any wide angle lenses that will work on the NIKKOR 1 to give about 24 35mm equivalent?

Tags: lens, nikon, ultra-wide

I like the look of the NIKKOR 1, but wish to have the option of a real wide angle len.  Can I get one at a reasonable price by using mount converts etc?

Answer (score 3):

There is a 10mm lens available for the Nikon 1 which will give you a 27mm FF equivalent field of view. There are no official lenses wider than that, and finding a lens to mount from another system will be difficult due to the 1 series' small sensor.

The widest rectilinear lenses for APS-C bodies are 10mm, so they're out. Mirco 43rds uses a smaller sensor, so has shorter focal lengths available so something like the Panasonic 7-14mm f/4.0 would be wide enough, however I don't know if a micro 43rds -> Nikon 1 adaptor exists.

It's easier to adapt older fully manual only lenses as you don;t have to worry about electronic aperture control and focus etc. the adaptor is merely a tube which holds the lens at the correct distance. However it will be difficult to find a old lens with a short enough focal length (as ultrawides weren't made for compact formats back in the manual days). So you're best bet might be a fisheye, but that comes with it's own issues.

One option that appears to be viable is a C mount -> Nikon 1 adaptor. The C mount is used for CCTV and machine vision applications, frequently with small sensor cameras so very short focal length lenses are available. However as some of these lenses are designed for low resolution video, the quality might not be up to much on a Nikon 1 body.

If wide angles are your thing, I would consider a system with a larger sensor, such as the Sony NEX line.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you define "reasonable price" but using a [Nikon FT1 adapter](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/acil/accessories/mount_adapter_ft1/) you can use Nikon F-mount lenses on the 1-series cameras. Pricing for that today is in the $200 USD range.

The widest lens I know of for the F-mount is the **Sigma 8-16mm**, which with the ~2.7x crop factor of the CX/1 sensor gives you roughly a **22-43mm** equivalent lens. Pricing for that today looks to be in the $600 USD range.

Answer (score 0):

Kowa 6mm and 4.8mm c mount lenses may help. The HC series cover more than the nominal 1 inch. Very high resolution.

There are many youtube and some Vimeo examples of the 6mm in action on BMPCC and GH4 cameras.